# POST to interaction-experimental/v1/events returns 500 error

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I'm doing a **POST** to **interaction-experimental/v1/events** with the following payload:

```
{
"ContactKey":"[key]",
"EventDefinitionKey":"[event-key-from-trigger]",
"Data": {
              "email" : "test",
          "id" : "123"
}
}
```

and I'm getting a

> 500 response error

Any clue what the causes could be?

Comment: Internal Service Error... can you add any detail at all? Debug logs, for instance?

Comment: I don't have anything, because it is an error that is sent from Salesforce Marketing Cloud:`{"documentation":"https://code.docs.exacttarget.com/rest/errors/500","errorcode":0,"message":"Internal Server Error"}`

Comment: Either your payload is incorrect, or you should contact support.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! It was actually a PK Constraint error in the DE that was tied to the contact.