# Internal Server Error from marketingcloudapis /interaction/v1/events

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, journeybuilder, contactbuilder, marketingcloudapi

Getting error every time that I try this request:

```
curl --request POST 'https://[MY SUBDOMAIN].rest.marketingcloudapis.com/interaction/v1/events' \ 
--header 'authorization: Bearer [TOKEN]' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "ContactKey": "example@example.com",
    "EventDefinitionKey":"APIEvent-01234567-1234-1234-1234-123456789012",
    "Data": {
        "email":"example@example.com"
        }
}'
```

```
{
  "documentation":"https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/error-handling.htm",
  "errorcode":0,
  "message":"Internal Server Error"
}
```

- If I have a typo on `EventDefinitionKey` the response tells me it does not exist
- If I let `data` empty the response tells me that data is missing email

It most probably has something to do with the `ContactKey` but I don't even know where to start...

PS: I know [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/73209/post-to-interaction-experimental-v1-events-returns-500-error) is very related, but it is from when the endpoint was experimental and the answer does not help

Comment: I will be honest, I have been unable to replicate your error. Best I can offer is verify that the contactkey is in an acceptable format, eventdefinitionkey is not corrupted or similar, etc.

Comment: I would check required fields on your de and also is the contact being deleted?